# PHP streams unexpected 0x0A

Tags: php, stream

I'm dealing with a pretty strange issue regarding streams, I believe it's caused by stream_copy_to_stream but I'm not really sure.

Pseudocode:

```
$reader = fopen($in_file, 'r'); // tried with rb as well

read X bytes from $reader and process the data

$writer = fopen($out_file, 'w'); // tried with wb as well
$filter = stream_filter_append($reader, 'filter_name', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $options);
stream_copy_to_stream($reader, $writer);
```

What happens:
Let's say that there are N bytes left in $reader when stream_copy_to_stream is called. The resulting file $out_file will have N bytes, but a 0x0A will be prepended to the file, and the last byte will be ignored. Example:

```
original file start: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001
original file end:   b3c1 c557 92bb 3fff d9

resulting file start: 0aff d8ff e000 104a 4649 4600 01
original file end:    b3 c1c5 5792 bb3f ff
```

At first, I was able to fix this problem by executing an ob_flush() before the stream_copy_to_stream() call. But now I'm running the code from the command line, from a queue(using Laravel/Artisan/Beanstalkd) and this doesn't work anymore. No matter how large the file is, the problem manifests. I really have no idea what's causing this.

Tried on both Windows and Linux, php 5.5 and 5.6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really have no idea how to relate that issue to mine.

Comment: I've tried to dig further more into the problem and it seems that this is not caused by the stream_copy_to_stream call, but by what happens within the filter itself. 0x0A is prepended to the read data on the first bucket read(the buffer is smaller than the file size). So as the $consumed variable is updated at each pass, because of the extra byte in the beginning, the last byte of the original file is not read at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a newline character passed after the headers are sent to the browser, injected probably by a package I'm using in my project. All I need to do know is find the file causing this.

Problem solved.

EDIT: It was a newline before the opening