# Sending image as a response stopped working

Tags: image, httpresponse, lumen

This piece fc code was working like a charm:

```
public static function File($relativeFilePath) {
        if (Storage::exists($relativeFilePath) == false) {
            $relativeFilePath = "/not_found.png";
        }
        $absoluteDiskPath = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
        $fullPath = $absoluteDiskPath.$relativeFilePath;
        $file = File::get($fullPath);
        $contentType = File::mimeType($fullPath);
        $response = response()->make($file, 200);
        $response->header("Content-Type", $contentType);
        return $response;

    }
```

Right now, instead of sending the image is sending a wrong file. PHP finds the image where it is stored, and sends the contents of it (doing a var_dump will pop the file contents in postman).

But acutally is showing a little white square.

I am stucked. Updated lumen, recover code from previous commit (which was working) and still the same). In the screen capture you can see the result.

Permissions on the storage folder is 777, to avoid permissions issues.
If i add the image to the public root folder and I access to it directly (HTTP server and not the whole Lumen framework) it is shown.
My HTTP server is nginx on vagrant

[image: Image view]

## UPDATE

I removed the header from the answer and the contents are shown in postman. Nevertheless, I opened it with a hexadecimal to compare the two original files:

The response is adding an weird 0x0A value at the beginning.

[image: Weird 0x0A]

How so?

Comment: How are the first/last bytes of the response?

Comment: Response: 0AFFD8FF E000104A
Original:     FFD8FFE0 00104A46

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014055/not-a-jpeg-file-starts-with-0x0a-0x4c-error

Comment: Im guessing it has something to do with the extention/format. I recommend trying another file as test. Otherwise, Im out of suggestions :)

Comment: The original file is without the 0x0A, so, when i open with php in lumen to retrieve it, it is adding that. It is a JPEG, and it does the same with png :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085904/php-streams-unexpected-0x0a

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing something is wrong with the content of the image and you're getting an error. You're not seeing the error, as it's trying to display it as an image, which isnt very successfull, which results in the blank image you are seeing.

I suggest you comment off this line: `$response->header("Content-Type", $contentType);`, that way you get the raw result back. My guess is that there is an error, which you then can fix/continue to debug.
<sub>And ofcource, when you're done, you uncomment it again</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The issue came by an extra empty line at the beginning of a PHP file.

Problem solved.